Which Zigbee repeaters are compatible with Philips Hue
I bought the Marmitek Link SE zigbee repeater thinking I would use it to extend the range of my Philips Hue hub, but now it's plugged in it appears to be asking for a gateway. I thought that because Philips Hue hubs use Zigbee (they happily talk to my zigbee bulbs) it would be able to act as a gateway (surely that's what it has to do to perform its function?) but I cannot get the Link SE to recognise it.
Can anyone either tell me if I have the wrong product, how to connect it if it should work or if I have misunderstood completely, please?

The Philips Hue system uses the Zigbee protocol, but it sadly does not accept any Zigbee device.
While most light bulbs (but not all) are supported, for other devices it’s extremely limited, with mostly only Hue and “friends of Hue” devices being supported.
Unless the device appears like a bulb somehow, it’s unlikely you may be able to have it join your Zigbee network. You can try to add it (until the device has joined the network it cannot participate), but I’m not convinced it will work.
But remember: nearly all Zigbee devices with an external power source, and that includes light bulbs, act as repeaters. So you are more likely to have success by simply adding bulbs accepted by the Hue bridge.

The lights are already recognised by Hue. In fact, they were very easy to add to the system and, because I linked Alexa to Hue, they were auto recognised by Alexa, too. The bulbs are EEGLO brand, but my problem is finding a repeater/Hue extender, not adding bulbs to Hue per se.

@MattW all your existing lights already act as repeaters. Want more range? Add a light. Note that many smart plugs present themselves as lights, so you can use one as well, even if you don’t plug anything into it. Have you tried using the “add light” feature in the app while your repeater is in pairing mode?

You could also try plugging the stick into your computer to try to find out what chip it uses. If you’re lucky enough it’s something like an nRF52840 which you could then re flash with a different firmware to make it look like a bulb and join your Hue network.
